# ImportError: libgomp.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python

Running `import graphlab` in an Anaconda2 virtualenv on a Google Cloud Compute Engine causes the following stack trace. It does not cause the stack trace when run locally on my machine.

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-86ee286b3296> in <module>()
----> 1 import graphlab
      2 import requests

/home/jbmlaird/anaconda2/envs/gl-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graphlab/__init__.pyc in <module>()
     57     (_os.path.exists(_os.path.join(_os.path.dirname(__file__), 'cython', 'libstdc++-6.dll')) and \
     58     _os.path.exists(_os.path.join(_os.path.dirname(__file__), 'cython', 'libgcc_s_seh-1.dll'))):
---> 59     from graphlab.data_structures.sgraph import Vertex, Edge
     60     from graphlab.data_structures.sgraph import SGraph
     61     from graphlab.data_structures.sarray import SArray

/home/jbmlaird/anaconda2/envs/gl-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graphlab/data_structures/__init__.py in <module>()
     23 
     24 from . import image
---> 25 from . import sframe
     26 from . import sarray
     27 from . import sgraph

/home/jbmlaird/anaconda2/envs/gl-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graphlab/data_structures/sframe.py in <module>()
     17 '''
     18 from .. import connect as _mt
---> 19 from ..connect import main as glconnect
     20 from ..cython.cy_flexible_type import infer_type_of_list
     21 from ..cython.context import debug_trace as cython_context

/home/jbmlaird/anaconda2/envs/gl-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graphlab/connect/main.py in <module>()
     24 # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
     25 
---> 26 from ..cython.cy_unity import UnityGlobalProxy
     27 from ..cython import cy_ipc
     28 from ..cython.cy_server import EmbeddedServer

ImportError: libgomp.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

`GraphLab Create` is installed, as is `Anaconda2`.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Fixed by running:

`sudo apt-get install libgomp1`

Comment: sometimes you need apt-get update and apt-get upgrade first

Comment: For Centos:
`yum install libgomp`