# Error: Can not import paddle core while this file exists

Tags: python-3.x, paddle-paddle, paddleocr

I am currently using intel i3 with **no gpu**,
I created a virtual environment in python with python version 3.10.11, while my current python version is 3.11.3

In the virtual env

I tried installing paddleocr using `pip install paddleocv` and `pip install paddlepaddle`

when I import paddleocr using `from paddleocr import PaddleOCR,draw_ocr`

I am getting error: `Error: Can not import paddle core while this file exists: d:\env\.venv\lib\site-packages\paddle\fluid\libpaddle.pyd`

`ImportError: DLL load failed while importing libpaddle: The specified module could not be found.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had also encountered this problem before, and I solved it by the command:

```
python -m pip install --force-reinstall paddlepaddle==2.5
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

The other answers didn't work for me, but luckily I found [this comment](https://github.com/PaddlePaddle/PaddleOCR/issues/10443#issuecomment-1644835824) suggesting to downgrade to version 2.4.2, so it finally worked.

So I just ran:
`python -m pip install --force-reinstall paddlepaddle==2.4.2`

And it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Got the same issue but resolved it by forcing the reinstallation with the latest version
`python -m pip install --force-reinstall paddlepaddle==[version]`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Got a similar issue while running on no GPU VM, `import paddle` failed with

```
Error: Can not import paddle core while this file exists: /home/XXXX/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paddle/fluid/libpaddle.so
.
.
.
ImportError: libgomp.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Tried reinstalling the package multiple times but running this `sudo apt-get install libgomp1` resolved the issue.

[ImportError: libgomp.so.1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43764699/13257364)